# Anything missing from my android project test setup?

Tags: java, android, robolectric, android-testing

I am currently building an android application and I am after the best testing setup in order to make my application bulletproof : ) If there is anything small/big missing please feel free to commend! : )

So my testing goes a bit like this:
(bear in mind that my application has a back-end server)

1. Junit tests with Robolectric on the application side against all the supported android versions.
2. Junit tests with mockito on the server side.
3. Integration tests with robolectric and a real instance of the back-end server. UPDATE:
   this will probably end up being instrumentation tests and a real instance of the back-end server as robolectric and the google play services that we are using in the project is a no go.
4. Instrumentation tests with a real instance of the back-end server against multiple devices (different screen resolutions etc.)  but against just a single version of the android API - probably the latest supported one. This would mean starting up multiple android virtual devices and running the tests on each one of them. I read that one can take screenshots of the screens, but I am not sure how we can verify that the screenshots are OK.
5. Running the application with monkey runner, again with a real server.
6. Performance tests where we mostly get to test the interaction of many devices with the back-end server at the same time. Not quite sure how one would get to run such tests for android.

All of these tests will be running on the TeamCity CI server. We are trying to use roboletric on as many of these tests as possible, as it's way faster than loading the tests on a device.

My question is, is there anything big/small missing from my setup, or are there any frameworks that could make it easier for us to run all these tests apart from the use of robolectric/android maven plugin/teamcity ?

Comment: I think your setup is way perfect than others. I would add some automated acceptance tests with appium or calabash. But most probably your point #4 covers this. I don't have any experience with instrumental tests :)

Comment: Instrumentation Tests and webdriver Test are different. With appium you can't access app classes. So they feel more real, bit much slower than espresso which has access to app classes.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using Robolectric, Robotium is worth checking out. More about it is discussed here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/522312/3152743) along with other methods of testing you might be interested in.

Comment: I've been doing quite a bit of investigation on the topic, I will provide an update on this in a week or so. There's a lot of frameworks that I wasn't aware of. Robotium is good indeed, but seems like espresso is newer and solves the synchronization issues while instrumenting.